# Testing Controller Concerns with Rspec on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, activesupport-concern

I am not able to access session or route paths (root_url) from the specs using anonymous controller on a controller concern.

Here is my code

```
module SecuredConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def logged_in?
    session[:user_info].present?
  end

  def redirect_to_login
    redirect_to login_path unless logged_in?
  end

  def redirect_to_home
    redirect_to root_path if logged_in?
  end
end
```

And spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe SecuredConcern, type: :controller do
  before do
    class FakesController < ApplicationController
      include SecuredConcern
    end
  end

  after { Object.send :remove_const, :FakesController }
  let(:object) { FakesController.new }
  # let(:session) {create(:session, user_info: '')}

  describe 'logged_in' do
    it "should return false if user is not logged in" do
      expect(object.logged_in?).to eq(false)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the trace:

```
Module::DelegationError:
       ActionController::Metal#session delegated to @_request.session, but @_request is nil: #<FakesController:0x00007f9856c04c20 @_action_has_layout=true, @rendered_format=nil, @_routes=nil, @_request=nil, @_response=nil>
     # ./app/controllers/concerns/secured_concern.rb:9:in `logged_in?'
     # ./spec/controllers/concerns/secured_concern_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NoMethodError:
     #   undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
     #   ./app/controllers/concerns/secured_concern.rb:9:in `logged_in?'
```

config is updated with `config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true`

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The console log said session delegated to @_request.session, but @_request is nil. My solution would be to create a fake method for FakeController, and the routes to that fake method. Then test the `logged_in?` in request spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I solved it by using `RSpec.shared_examples`

In my controller spec where I am including this concern:

```
# spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe HomeController, type: :controller do
  it_behaves_like 'SecuredConcern', HomeController
end
```

And in my concern spec:

```
# spec/shared/secured_concern_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.shared_examples 'SecuredConcern' do |klass|
  describe '#logged_in?' do
    it "should return true if user is logged in" do
      session[:user_info] = {uid: 1}
      expect(subject.logged_in?).to eq(true)
    end

    it "should return false if user is not logged in" do
      expect(subject.logged_in?).to eq(false)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. Where did `subject` come from?

Comment: @RicardoGreen `subject` is an instance of the described class, provided by Rspec itself either [implicitly](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject) (the first parameter passed to the `describe` method), or [explicitly](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/subject/explicit-subject) inside the `describe` block. To access the class itself, you can use `described_class`.